# Searching for Empty Cells in a Loop

Tags: vba, excel

I'm writing a script that if any cell in column M of Sheet2 is changed to "Special," the row number of that cell is copied to column B of Sheet12.  If the the row number is the largest in the column, it is added to the end.  If not, a row is copied from a template row and inserted (along with the row number) so that all the numbers in column B are sequential.

The code for inserting/copying mid-sequence numbers works great, but it isn't working to add the largest number to the end.  I'm not getting an error; it's just not working.  Here's the code (in Sheet2):

```
If Target.column = 13 Then

    Dim cell As Integer
    Dim l As Long

    cell = ActiveCell.Row

    If ActiveCell.Value = "Special" Then
        With Sheet12
            For l = .Cells(rows.count, "B").End(xlUp).Row To 3 Step -1
                If .Cells(l, 2).Value = vbNullString And .Cells(l - 1, 2).Value < cell Then
                    Sheet12.Cells(l, 2).Value = cell
                ElseIf .Cells(l, 2).Value > cell And .Cells(l - 1, 2).Value < cell Then
                    Sheet12.Cells(l, 2).EntireRow.Insert shift:=xlDown
                    Sheet12.Range("A3").EntireRow.Copy Sheet12.Cells(l, 2).EntireRow
                    Sheet12.Cells(l, 2).Value = cell
                End If
            Next
        End With
    End If
End If
```

The portion of the code that needs to be changed is `If .Cells(l, 2).Value = vbNullString And .Cells(l - 1, 2).Value < cell Then`. I've tried different ways of checking for an empty cell (i.e. isempty(), using "", etc.) and referencing the cells differently, with sheet names.  Any ideas? Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Why loop cell by cell? `GoTo > Special Cells` can be used in VBA: http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/special-cells.htm

Comment: I think I need to loop cell by cell, because it needs to be checked first to see if the number is between existing numbers (to execute copy/insert script), or the largest (to just be added at the end).

Comment: there is no need to do everything at once, you are trying to find the place where you should insert the new value in column B, a simpler method is to add it to the end of column B and then sort it as you want

Comment: Ah, I see. I will give it a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the loop was starting at the first non-blank cells in column B, so it was not possible for that value to be vbnullstring.  Below is working code:

```
If Target.column = 13 Then

     Dim cell As Long
     Dim l As Long

     cell = ActiveCell.Row

     If ActiveCell.Value = "Special" Then
         If Sheet12.[B4].Value = vbNullString Then
             Sheet12.[B4].Value = cell
         Else
             With Sheet12
                 For l = .Cells(rows.count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1 To 4 Step -1
                     If .Cells(l, 2).Value = vbNullString And .Cells(l - 1, 2).Value < cell Then
                         Sheet12.Cells(l, 2).Value = cell
                         Exit For
                     ElseIf .Cells(l - 1, 2).Value > cell And .Cells(l - 2, 2).Value < cell Then
                         Sheet12.Cells(l - 1, 2).EntireRow.Insert shift:=xlDown
                         Sheet12.Range("A3").EntireRow.Copy Sheet12.Cells(l - 1, 2).EntireRow
                         Sheet12.Cells(l - 1, 2).Value = cell
                         Exit For
                     End If
                 Next
             End With
         End If
     ElseIf ActiveCell.Value = vbNullString Or ActiveCell.Value = "Normal" Then
             With Sheet12
                 For l = .Cells(rows.count, "B").End(xlUp).Row To 4 Step -1
                     If .Cells(l, 2).Value = cell Then
                         .Cells(l, 2).EntireRow.Delete
                     End If
                 Next
             End With
     End If
 End If
```

**Note: this is not the most efficient way to execute, as mentioned in the comments; however, if someone is having a similar issue, I wanted to explain the fix.**